# Microwave Crust

Tags: baking, microwave, crust

I've done a lot of microwave baking (and have created some delicious treats!), however I've never found a way to get a crust with the microwave.

Now I understand the science behind a microwave and realize that there's no way to crust the outside of a loaf of microwave bread or to make cookies not melt everywhere. However, I have tried things like using some egg wash (it gives a bit of texture to the outside, but it's not quite a crust) or spraying with water/oil mid-baking.

Has anybody found the holy grail of baking in the microwave?

Comment: The usual reasons (whether in a microwave or an oven) for not getting a bread crust crisp ... and for not getting cookies, crumbles, pizza crisp ... are actually opposite: In the first case, lack of steam, in the second case, presence of steam....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an complete answer but a clue-

I have noticed that some hot pockets will come with a cardboard cage that seems to be lined with very thin foil. In the microwave the hot pockets are actually browned. It would seem that the foil is able to heat up past 212F and do the job.

I have seen products that seem to do the same thing:

[http://www.amazon.com/Corning-Microwave-Browning-Grill-Handles/dp/B003YQGMY0/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YQGMY0)

but I have not used them.

I haven't been brave enough to experiment because of the danger of fire etc. Good luck on your quest.

Comment: this is brilliant!